# ODK Collect Image Quality

Tags: image, collect, odk

As now the smartphones are coming with 16 MP cameras, and the picture size is coming to 5 MB. Uploading them on Mobile data will take some time and also more data, resulting in poor performance of App.

Is there any way, that the ODK collect resizes the image questions to a specified dimensions and quality.

This will help improve the performance of App.

Comment: If you are still interested in this being a feature, please consider commenting on this proposal - https://github.com/opendatakit/xforms-spec/issues/79

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ImageWidget.java](https://code.google.com/p/opendatakit/source/browse/src/org/odk/collect/android/widgets/ImageWidget.java?repo=collect)

ODK Collect resizes to the screen size, but you can change

```
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

to a a fixed max resolution...

```
    // Only add the imageView if the user has taken a picture
    if (mBinaryName != null) {
        mImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        mImageView.setId(QuestionWidget.newUniqueId());
        Display display =
            ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .getDefaultDisplay();
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = display.getHeight();

        File f = new File(mInstanceFolder + File.separator + mBinaryName);

        if (f.exists()) {
            Bitmap bmp = FileUtils.getBitmapScaledToDisplay(f, screenHeight, screenWidth);
            if (bmp == null) {
                mErrorTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        }

        mImageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        mImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Collect.getInstance().getActivityLogger().logInstanceAction(this, "viewButton", 
                                    "click", mPrompt.getIndex());
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                Uri uri = MediaUtils.getImageUriFromMediaProvider(mInstanceFolder + File.separator + mBinaryName);
                    if ( uri != null ) {
                    Log.i(t,"setting view path to: " + uri);
                    i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                    try {
                        getContext().startActivity(i);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            getContext().getString(R.string.activity_not_found, "view image"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```